# Customize the default font family on Strapi V4 headless CMS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi, headless-cms

How can I change the default font-family of the admin **Strapi v4** dashboard? because I found nothing of how we can change the default **Strapi v4** font-family